# HTML table with single 25% column uses 100% width, why?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table that dynamically gets filled by data using 4 columns.
Each column is defined to use 25% of space.
Works fine if the table contains at least one row with 4 data cells.
If the dynamic data just fills one cell (1 filled cell), the column uses 100% instead of 25% of the width.

How can this be resolved *without* adding empty cells? Is this possible somehow?

Sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/ydm391mz/

```
<div id="top">
    <table>
        <tr><td>Just 25%</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

and

```
#top 
{
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    width:100%;
}
#top table 
{
    width:100%;
}
#top td 
{
    width:25%;
    background-color:#aaaaaa;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `display:inline-block;`. But this don't forget to [remove extra space](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) where there are 4 `td`s

```
#top td {
    width:25%;
    background-color:#aaaaaa;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ydm391mz/3/)

Comment: Thanks, this is the solution! My updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/ydm391mz/3/

Answer (score 3):

Your tr gets autofilled, you can do this for example:

```
<div id="top">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Just 25%</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

You tell the HTML you got 4 td´s with text (even if only one has text), and every single column has 25% then.

**EDIT:**

There was a question anout what if he wants more than 4 `<td>`'s but only the first one beeing 25%

The first part is simple, you just add another `<td>`

```
<div id="top">
    <table>
        <tr><td>Just 25%</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

The second part is CSS now, there is for sure not only one solution for doing this, my css looks like this, so only the first `<td>` gets the 25% width:

```
#top td {
    background-color:#aaaaaa;
}

#top td:nth-child(1) {
    width:25%;
}
```

Comment: I think this is the best option for achieving the desired outcome while preserving the overall table structure without overriding the `display: table-cell;` agent style sheet.

Comment: @ThisClark And what if he need 5 <td> ?

Comment: @Nvan Then he inserts a 5th <td> and tells the css td {width: 20%}

Comment: But he probably want only one row with 25%

Comment: Hi, I would use this solution if I could add empty `<td>`, but I asked for a solution where I don't add empty cells.

Comment: @basZero This is a clean method i think. I don't know if you edited the post but for first i did not read about "i don't want to use empty cells"... sorry for this :) But maybe you can use it another time :)

Answer (score 2):

you can try this

```
#top td {
    display:block;
    width:25% ;
    background-color:#aaaaaa;
}
```

I wouldn't use it because you could mess up the table when adding more columns, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

You have only one column, so it auto fills the entire width.

Add one more column and it will change to 25%.

Check it out here:

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}
table td {
  background-color: #aaaaaa;
}
#twentyfive {
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td id="twentyfive">Just 25%</td>
      <td>Everything else</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.